# "To be" VS "to have been" ( the impersonal passive)

Tags: passive-voice, to-infinitive, perfect-aspect, impersonal-verb

Is there any difference between (1) and (2)?

(1) Almodovar's film was considered to be the most innovative.
(2) Almodovar's film was considered to have been the most innovative.

---

(1): means that the film is still considered the most innovative
(2): Implies that the film is no longer considered to be the most innovative.

This is what I think, and I wanted to confirm this idea.

Comment: Yes, what you think is correct

Comment: Thank you @FumbleFingers

Answer (score 1):

No, that is incorrect. (I respectfully disagree with the comment above.)

Sentence 1 means that the film was consider to be the most innovative at that time. For example, a movie critic wrote in 2010 that Almodovar's film was the most innovative in 2010.

Sentence 2 uses the perfect aspect, implying an earlier time. This would usually mean that the film was consider to have been the most innovative at some earlier time. For example, a movie critic wrote in 2010 that Almodovar's film had been the most innovative in 1995 (but perhaps was no longer the most innovative in 2010).<sup>1</sup>

Because you say "was considered" (past tense), neither sentence implies anything about how Almodovar's film is currently considered.

---

<sup>1</sup> People sometimes use the perfect aspect to indicate something that happened before the present (i.e., the time at which the sentence is spoken or written). In that case, sentence 2 would mean the same as sentence 1.

Comment: Yes, at *that time** versus "up until that time".